# datagridview add rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a simple datagridview on my form. I added a 2 columns -- one of a button type and the other of text type. I am trying to add some rows just as a test but I'm not seeing them.

Below is the code. It must be something simple but what do I need to do see my new rows?

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = "BUTTON";
        button.Text="BUTTON";
        newRow.SetValues(button, "TEST");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to my same problem. I am still reading to see what they discovered.

[Why can't I see the DataGridViewRow added to a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698356/why-cant-i-see-the-datagridviewrow-added-to-a-datagridview)

One solution appears to be to call CreateCells on the row after it is created.

```
     newRow.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
```